# Message Level Security .ASMX .Net4 webservice with X.509

Tags: c#, web-services, .net-4.0, asmx, x509

I have a .net 4 .asmx webservice. I am required to implement message level security using X.509 certs.I can create certs using makecert.exe. All examples I have seen so far refer to .net2 and VS2005 with WSE 2/3.0, or .wcf services. I have tried to configure my web.config by adding these tags but it doesn't work. I mean a client request without certification still goes through.

Service Endpoints

```
          Upon deployment, the following identity element should be removed or replaced to reflect the 
          identity under which the deployed service runs.  If removed, WCF will infer an appropriate identity 
          automatically.

      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost"/>
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
  </service>
  <!--end mls-->
</services>
<!--mls-->
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="WCFServiceCertificate.Service1Behavior">
       To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment 
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
       To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information 
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
      <serviceCredentials>
        <clientCertificate>
          <authentication certificateValidationMode="PeerTrust"/>
        </clientCertificate>
        <serviceCertificate findValue="WCFServer" storeLocation="CurrentUser" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName"/>
      </serviceCredentials>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<!--end mls-->
```

Does anyone have an idea how I can achieve this?

Comment: ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF or ASP.NET Web API should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Comment: In particular, ASMX has no support for WS-Security. Use WCF for  this.

Comment: @JohnSaunders I think you may have misspelt a tag. I assume ac# was supposed to have remained c# (not sure enough to change it back myself).